# loop to identify a sum and then get the position of that sum

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I have this data.frame called EXAMPLE, with 4 variables:

```
date <- c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013)
new_york <- c(10,20,22,28)
berlin <- c(0,51,45,12)
tokyo <- c(2,15,20,13)

EXAMPLE <- data.frame(date, new_york, berlin, tokyo)
```

**I want to identify, in each column, in which position was summed at least 50 and also store that sum. For example, in the column new_york, was summed 52 at row 3.**

I was thinking in something like this below, but it didn't work:

```
x <- 1
  while(sum(EXAMPLE$berlin[1:x]) <= 50) {
    a <-x
  }
```

I appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a 'cumulative sum'. In R this can be calculated by `cumsum(EXAMPLE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
out <- lapply(EXAMPLE[,-1], cumsum)
names(out) <- paste0(names(out), "_cumulative")
options(width=123, length=99999)
cbind(EXAMPLE, out)
#   date new_york berlin tokyo new_york_cumulative berlin_cumulative tokyo_cumulative
# 1 2010       10      0     2                  10                 0                2
# 2 2011       20     51    15                  30                51               17
# 3 2012       22     45    20                  52                96               37
# 4 2013       28     12    13                  80               108               50
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the equivalent `tidy` version of @r2evans answer...

```r
library(dplyr)

EXAMPLE %>% 
   mutate(across(new_york:tokyo, 
                 cumsum, 
                 .names = "cumsum_{.col}")
          )

#>   date new_york berlin tokyo cumsum_new_york cumsum_berlin cumsum_tokyo
#> 1 2010       10      0     2              10             0            2
#> 2 2011       20     51    15              30            51           17
#> 3 2012       22     45    20              52            96           37
#> 4 2013       28     12    13              80           108           50
```